# UWP C# Interpret UART serial via Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, serial-port, uart

Hi I'm working on an UWP app (C#) that connects via Bluetooth to a device providing a UART serial connection.

**The problem is:**

I simply can not make any sense of the data I'm receiving via the UART serial read Bluetooth characteristic.
The image bellow shows an example of the data I'm receiving:

[image]

**How do I try to decode the data:**

```
byte[] data = readData();
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)
```

Is there any special encoding required to interpret UART data?

Comment: 1. Who if not you knows what your device sends? 2. Why do you think it must be string?

Comment: I actually don't know what it sends so I guessed strings.
Is there a way to find out because it's just some cheep whether station.

Comment: If you have no documentation for the protocol the only way to find out what it sends is to dump data to file (as raw bytes, not bad to dump as HEX and as DEC) and the compare with data you know. If it is weather station it should send temperature, pressure and probably other info. So raw binary dump should help.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip! I guess It's some kind of binary protocol. I will try to reverse engineer it.

Comment: That looks eerily like junk caused by a mismatching BAUD rate.  Does your BAUD rate match on each side?

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = BitConverter.ToString(data)
```

Don't know if this helps to get your data.